# How do I get a value from PHP's defualt session when a custom session handler is in use?

Tags: php, session

I have a non CMS page in which a session value is stored using PHP's default session handler. ie:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['MyVar'] = true;
```

On another page, which is part of the CMS, I need to test whether the variable is true or not. But, the CMS uses it's own session handler, so when I try to read the variable, it's undefined, because it's looking for it in the CMS's session storage system, not PHP's default.

How can I switch over for a moment and read a value from the default session store, and then reinstate the CMS's so that it functions correctly?

Something like:

```
$SessionHandler = session_get_current_handler(); // save the CMS session handler
session_use_default(); // Use PHP's default handler
$Value = $_SESSION['MyVar']; // Get the value I need
session_set_handler($SessionHandler); // Restore CMS handler
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At some point you will need to call `session_start()` in order to populate the `$_SESSION` superglobal array. You 'might' be able to call `session_write_close()`, change the handler, and do `session_start()` again.

Try it, it will look something like

```
$Sessionhandler = session_get_current_handler();
session_use_default();
session_start();
$value = $_SESSION['var'];
session_write_close();
session_set_handler($Sessionhandler);
session_start();
```

I almost doubt it is going to work though. The only reason it 'might' work is because of the `session_write_close()` as PHP normally throws an `E_NOTICE` if you try to call `session_start()` twice.

Depending upon the implementation, it might try to get the data again. But a lot of people over at the [documentation comments](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) have seen weird things happen when calling `session_start()` twice, even after `session_write_close()`